# When to use f:view and f:subview

Tags: jsf-2, view, facelets, subview

I am not sure what are the benefits of using `<f:view>` and `<f:subview>`.
I noticed that one could write JSF pages without using them.

What are the benefits of using those tags?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

### <f:view>

The [`<f:view>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/view.html) is only useful if you want to explicitly specify/override any of the available attributes such as `locale`, `encoding`, `contentType`, etc or want to attach some phase listeners. E.g.

```
<f:view locale="#{user.locale}" encoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html">
```

If you don't specify it, then the sane JSF defaults will just be used instead, which is respectively `UIViewRoot#getLocale()`, `UTF-8` and the closest match of `Accept` request header. Noted should be that the closest match of `Accept` request header isn't always entirely right. Sometimes it results in `application/xhtml+xml` because of the presence of `.xhtml` extension in the URL in case of Facelets and the webbrowser not being configured to interpret it as `text/html` by default (like MSIE). You'd really like to avoid this wrong content type by explicitly setting it to `text/html`.

Note that it doesn't matter where you put it in the template. You can even put it in template client as immediate child of `<ui:define>`. However, canonical place is as immediate child of `<html>` and thus wrapping both `<h:head>` and `<h:body>`. This is also the way how it's done in legacy JSP where it's actually *required*. In Facelets it's optional and accounted as meta data.

#### See also:

- [Our XHTML wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xhtml/info)
- [Is it possible to use JSF+Facelets with HTML 4/5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935759/is-it-possible-to-use-jsffacelets-with-html-4-5/)
- [JSF 2.0 not rendering any page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865344/jsf-2-0-not-rendering-any-page/)

---

### <f:subview>

The [`<f:subview>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/subview.html) will create another naming container context. This is particularly useful when you want to reuse an include file which in turn contain fixed component IDs more than once in the same view root, otherwise you will get duplicate component ID errors. However, since JSF 2.0 such an include file can better be a composite component which is by itself already a naming container.

If you don't specify it, then it won't harm if you don't reuse a component with the same ID physically multiple times in the view.

#### See also:

- [Why <h:panelGroup> id is not found when I access through <f:subview> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670720/why-hpanelgroup-id-is-not-found-when-i-access-through-fsubview-tag/)
- [Binding attribute causes duplicate component ID found in the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101755/im-getting-duplicate-id-error-after-adding-binding-attribute/)
- [Difference between <f:subview> and <ui:composition> tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273902/difference-between-fsubview-and-uicomposition-tags/)

Comment: If I need to conditionally render HTML (like table rows), is subview a good choice? I can't seem to find another component with the rendered attribute that doesn't render a HTML tag.

Comment: @Rinaldo: [ui:fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946985/the-right-way-to-conditional-rendering-of-non-jsf-components/15947948#15947948)