# How to change Content-Type header in JSF 2.2

Tags: jsf-2, xhtml, http-headers, content-type, wildfly-8

How can I make JSF send http header
`Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml;charset=UTF-8` instead of current
`Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8`?

Adding following snippet in `web.xml` had no effect.

```xml
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>xhtml</extension>
    <mime-type>application/xhtml+xml</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

My sample file `webapp/sample.xhtml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<f:view>
    <h:outputLabel value="Hello, world"/>
</f:view>
</html>
```

Environment:
JSF 2.2, WildFly 8.2

Comment: Because `application/xhtml+xml` is proper MIME type of XHTML5 http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/introduction.html#html-vs-xhtml

Comment: Yes, I know, but did you read the answer in the link I posted regarding IE?

Comment: Yes I did, thanks for that one. It still feels good to know how to change that setting, not just being glad for reasonable defaults.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set it in `<f:view>` as below:

```
<f:view contentType="application/xhtml+xml">
```

However, this is the wrong value for HTML. JSF/XHTML generates HTML output which should really have `text/html` content type. Explanation can be found in the answer to [When to use f:view and f:subview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8883476/when-to-use-fview-and-fsubview), particularly in the "See also" links in that answer.

Comment: And the remarkable thing is that I did not know this, but google was my friend. Make it yours to